# How would one create a "start button" on a website similar to some Korean games?

Tags: javascript

Some games have buttons that would actually let you click them and you'd log right into the game.  How does the web browser get permission to do this without plugins? Perhaps the client  registers a custom protocol URL?

They used to be popular a few years back - I can't remember any implementations off the top of my head. On desktop browsers, if your game client was installed clicking 'Play' on the home page would boot up the game begin it with you already signed in. It was popular with arcade games so you could browse the sessions on the web and then simply hit 'Start'. You didn't need any browser plugins.

Comment: I'm interested in this topic, but I have no idea what you're talking about. How about showing an example? or at least mention the platform (desktop? mobile?)

Comment: @PandaPajama I added a bit more detail - perhaps this is enough?

Comment: If I remember correctly, this game does what you describe. http://dungeonfighter.nexon.net/
I don't have this installed anymore so I can't confirm.

Comment: Doesn't Battlefield 3 work that way? But I think it requires a browser plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not seen any games that do this, but I can think of a few ways to achieve this. Keep in mind that any solution will be browser and OS dependent, so you must offer alternative ways to start your game.

In general, my approach would consist of running your game's executable file from the browser. Here are some ideas I just made out. I'm not really sure whether or not they work for your purposes, or if they even work at all, but they may give you some ideas.

1. `WScript.Shell`. Only works on IE, but is probably your most flexible choice.
2. The `mozilla.org/process` XPCOM component would do the same thing in Firefox.
3. Execute the program from a signed Java applet. I haven't done applets in ages, but last time I checked, you could access local data XOR the internet from an applet, if it is properly signed.
4. Execute the program from a flash applet. This would be very similar to the Java applet.
5. Have the browser download a file with a custom extension, which your game previously registered. This requires a confirmation dialog, but is probably the most portable.
6. Have the link point to a custom URL scheme/activity which was previously registered by your game. This only works on iOS/Android, and is the mobile analog of the previous point.
7. Use a plugin. Most likely your game installer requires admin privileges, so use these privileges to install plugins for the currently found browser(s).
8. Make the button into a link to the locally installed game executable (via `file://`). This will fail when the game is not installed though.

But, if you can find a working example, you can check the page source, and at least get a hint of how they're doing it.

Comment: Custom URL schemes work on desktop platforms too (though recently they have sometimes been restricted due to security problems with poorly implemented handlers). For example, Steam uses them.

Comment: @KevinReid: You're right. I have no experience with custom URL schemes on the desktop though.